# Angular 2+ create dynamic modules

Tags: angular, module, tabular

I would like to know if it's possible de create `dynamic modules` at runtime.
The modules I would like to instanciate would be the `same`.
Indeed, I have a `table of activities` that can have `child` activities.
 And these child activities `can have more children`...

The idea is to show a children table below the parent one, recursivly. When a row is selected in a table, a child table is shown below.

[image]

I use `smart-table` modules (from `ng2admin`, quite popular).

Comment: Create a component of the thing you want to repeat, then use *ngFor.

Comment: Isn't ngfor used for repeat vars? Idk if it's possible for modules

Comment: It is, so just do that. and use @Input() in your components to pass the data to it.

Comment: I see let me try

Comment: are the modules repeated going to be injected ? I need to call some services

Comment: You can do everything that you want like a normal component

Comment: @Carsten thanks it works good :)